# Scheduling tags for the community bulletin board

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin-board

We have a community bulletin board on our site. Here's a near-current screenshot of the homepage:

[image: (screenshot)]

You can see four items listed sub "Community Bulletin". The first two are marked "event" and called "miketz questions" (linking to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miketz) and "chanuka questions (linking to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka) respectively. The next is marked "blog"; and the last, "meta". The latter two are there because the Stack Exchange software chose them. (One links to a recent Stack Exchange bog post and the other to an active post here on meta. [You can read more on how items are chosen for the community bulletin board.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129559)) But the first two items are there because a site moderator put them there: we (the mods) have been intermittently setting temporally topical tags as 'events' on the community bulletin board. The ability to do so was a big part of why Mi Yodeya pushed for something like a community bulletin board before we ever got one.

I have a question, though. We've mostly been setting these 'events' to run during the time period of the *parasha*, holiday, or the like. For example, the Miketz 'event' runs approximately from after *Shabas parashas Vayeshev* until *Shabas parashas Miketz*, and the Chanuka 'event' runs approximately for the eight days of Chanuka. So two questions, actually:

- Is that start time good, or should temporally topical tags be 'events' starting earlier or later? (Feel free to specify how much earlier/later.)
- Is that end time good, or should temporally topical tags be 'events' ending earlier or later? (Feel free to specify how much earlier/later.)

If your answers to these two questions depend on one another, then combine them in one answer, below; otherwise, post them as separate answers, please. Then, if someone's posted an answer that could be yours, upvote it instead of posting separately; and downvote answers you disagree with. We can assess the community's mind by looking at the votes. (Don't bother voting this question up/down, as it doesn't propose any schedule for the future.)

Comment: Although you could vote the question up to thank msh210 for his effort (and it is mostly him) at maintaining the community board.

Answer (score 1):

For the weekly parsha these times are good, spanning the time when most of us do most of our regular study of the target text.

Comment: I wonder though whether Monday through Sunday or Tuesday through Monday will better capture when people are thinking about the _parasha_ (or when they're able to post things that they had previously thought about the _parasha_).

Comment: Good question.  At that point in time, will people need the community event to remind them that they can post on the just-ended parsha?  Or will seeing the event for the next one, and (with luck) having seen several questions tagged for the ended one, be enough?

Comment: True. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

For holidays, I think it's worth starting the event a few days in advance (3-4), as that will be when people will be preparing and perhaps thinking of questions.  This year we saw questions about Chanukah in advance, and I seem to recall that's typical.  (The event is "(holiday) questions", not "holiday", so I don't think this is confusing.)  The event should run through the end of the holiday.

I'm not including minor single-day observances like Tu Bishvat and fast days in this.  Those should run for the day.  The only one of those that seems to entail a lot of advance focus is Tish B'av, but an event for the three weeks covers that.